# Use <component> that was imported in the parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm building a component that manages other components.
It dynamically render components in specific places depending on the `props` and `inputs`, much like an orchestrator.

#### Use case

My orchestrator have the following placeholders, like a grid (p1 ... p6):

```
|-p1-|-p2-|-p3-|
|-p4-|-p5-|-p6-|
```

In a given moment, it renders the component `C1` into `p2` and `C2` into `p6`:

```
|-p1-|-C1-|-p3-|
|-p4-|-p5-|-C2-|
```

In another moment, it replaces the `C1` by `C3`:

```
|-p1-|-C3-|-p3-|
|-p4-|-p5-|-C2-|
```

#### The problem

Given this dynamism, I can't (as far as I know) use `slots`. So I'm using `component` tags with the `:is` prop in order to dynamically render the correct component. The problem is that in order for the `:is` to work, I must have the component defined in my orchestrator/manager component. And I would like to keep it separated for reuse, doesn't make sense to import the components there. One solution would be to [globally register](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration) the components. I would like to avoid that if possible. Is there a way? I'm open to any kind of reflection-magic you may think n_n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the component via a prop like this:

**Orchestrator.vue**

```vue
<component :is="comp"/>
```

```es6
export default {
  props: ['comp']
}
```

**Test.vue**

```vue
<orchestrator :comp="MyComponent"/>
```

```es6
import Orchestrator from './orchestrator.vue'
import MyComponent from './my-component.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Orchestrator,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      MyComponent,
    };
  },
}
```

Comment: I think `import MyComponent from './my-component.vue'` is exactly what OP is trying to avoid

Comment: My impression was OP didn't want to import the component from within the orchestrator component, which this solution avoids by requiring the component to be passed in via a prop. Orchestrator is not tied to any particular component imports.

Comment: Can't believe. I tried that but didn't but the component in the `data`. -___- 
Feeling stupid, Thanks @DecadeMoon and also thanks @Phil!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components), loaded dynamically.

For example...

```html
<component :is="p2Replacement"></component>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    p2Replacement: null
  }
},
methods: {
  setP2Replacement(component) {
    this.p2Replacement = () => import(`path/to/${component}.vue`)
  }
}
```

And call it like `setP2Replacement('C1')` or `setP2Replacement('C3')`.

The fixed parts in the `import` expression are required so Webpack can include the appropriate files using a glob pattern. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context